# Responsive design for WordPress menu

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am just developing a child theme of WordPress twenty eleven theme. The live demo can be seen [here](http://modulesoft.info/projects/valuepayroll/). As WordPress has already responsive support I am also doing my theme in responsive for that I am customizing my theme CSS. For some of the part I am done. In my menu part I am facing some problems. I have two types of menus. One which doesn't have dropdowns and the others which have dropdowns. Now I am facing the problem in the menus which have dropdowns in responsive.  So can someone kindly help me here?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a design issue than a technical one. I would recommend either 1) turning the drop down menus into accordion menus (e.g., [tiny accordion](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-accordion/index.html)), or 2) extending the drop down menu region and increasing its z-index so that you can only hover over the drop down and not activate anything that appears underneath it. For your design, this might mean increasing the z-index and using something like `margin-top: -2px;` on the drop down menu's children.

The idea of responsive design, however, is that you make it available for small devices, like smart phones. Since smart phones that use touch don't have hover states, you're probably better offer using suggestion 1 above, where a user clicks on the initial menu, which then displays its sub-menu.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Here is one of the reference link http://kmrhospital.cz.cc/. You can see how the dropdown menus have been done in responsive style. So I just want like this. One thing I want to tell you that I don't prefer jQuery or javascript in menu part. I want simple html with css.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to change the `#access #header-right-menu ul ul` to have `position: relative;` and get rid of the float and add `width: 100%;`. This will make the menus push down the other menus when hovered over. You'll have to continue from there, since the code will need restructured. As I said before, though, the reason to have a responsive site in the first place is for mobile users. Mobile users won't be able to hover (at least on touch devices).